# Update variable inside ng-include template once a promise is kept

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-ng-include, angular-http

I'm in an interesting conundrum.

In my app, I am using a recursive `<script>` which is referred to in my main page via an `ng-include`:

```
<div ng-include="'theTemplate.html'" onload="one=features.items.one"></div>
```

The data for `features.items.one` is loaded via external api using `$http` and is set when the `$http` promise is kept.

**The problem is**, that the `ng-include` loads before the promise is kept, and when the promise does complete, the `{{one}}` INSIDE the script does not update (because `ng-include` creates a new scope)

How can I get the variable inside the script to update when the promise completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending my comment:

```
<div ng-if="your condition">
<div ng-include="'theTemplate.html'" onload="one=features.items.one"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me build a recursive tree (http://codepen.io/viniciuspires/pen/yNeRrR?editors=101). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a controller, and consider refactoring to a service in due course

```
<div ng-include="'theTemplate.html'" ng-controller="myCtrl"></div>
```

and then add a controller

```
xxx.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, Features) {
  $http request.then(function(data) {
    $scope.one = data.items.one;
  })
})
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. The problem is that the `ng-include` doesn't get updates from the original controller. It kind of creates its own subversion

Comment: the controller should be connected to the include file, not its parent

Comment: Hmmm... would I be able to access variables from the script in the overall page? I presume no